# What determines default row height for a new file in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet to act as a template. It's set up and working as expected.
When I copy the template to a new file (right click on tab > Copy to > New/existing spreadsheet) it copies the template to the new file, everything works as expected except the row heights are different in the two files.

I don't remember changing row height when I was making the template, but the two files are different - the template row width default is 17px and the new/existing copy has a default row height of 21px.

Where is the default row-height value set?
Or, how do I make sure the template exports the row height setting when copies are made?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there is no setting for global width/height value.

but you are able to copy-paste it:

[image]

Comment: I incorrectly wrote 'row width' where I meant to write 'row height' - corrected now in the question.